# How can a question be answered without being viewed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image] How can a question be answered without being viewed? Makes no sense to me. See screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps answered by the poster? I'm not sure it counts the poster as a viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are buffered and written to disk periodicially so they can be batched up.

Therefore you can see zero views for a while until the # of buffered views reaches the threshold and are all spooled out to the database.

This is less of an issue on high volume sites where views are being incremented a lot more rapidly.